# Como conectar Xamarim com o Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Olá, baixei o Visual Studio semana passada com o principal objetivo o desenvolvimento mobile. O Visual pediu a instalação do Xamarim e afins, e fiz tudo, poreeem, depois de todo instalação, o visual diz que nao tenho o xamarim.

[image: Visual pedindo xamarim]

Comment: Isso aparece após você abrir/criar um projeto Mobile Xamarin? @mayla-campos

Comment: Verifique no `Adcionar/Remover Programas` se existe `Xamarin`. Caso contrário terá que baixar.